# Not able to install 'mnormt' package in R 3.6.2

Tags: r, r-package, psych

I am trying to install psych package in R 3.6.2 but after installing the same my library function is giving below error for psych:

[image]

So i tried installing "mnormt" package which i am not able to install and getting below error:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the tag version to install command, for example:

```
devtools::install_github('cran/mnormt@R-3.0.3')
```

Check what version you need and replace the tag after the '@'.

Also. try restarting R if possible.

If you still get erros,try

Install an older version of the package, one compatible with the version of R I am running.

R version is 3.6.3 was released on feb 2020. Try upgrading your R to version 4.x which is latest.

I go to the `mnormt` page and click on "old sources" https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mnormt/

I see that version 2.0.0 is the most recent release which is prior to my version of R

Following these pages: "Installing older versions of packages" https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages I copy the relevant url into this code and run it in R

```
packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mnormt/mnormt_2.0.0.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Comment: i tried your code but it's giving me error:

Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  HTTP error 404.
  No commit found for the ref R-3.6.2

Comment: Okay, I've updated the instructions. Please check if that works.

Comment: i am getting below error while installing with latest R-3.6.3

ERROR: this R is version 3.6.3, package 'mnormt' requires R >= 4.0.0
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mnormt_2.0.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Yes, it means that this is compatible with R version 4.0 or greater. Please upgrade your R version.

Comment: Great. If possible, mark the above ans as accepted so that others will be able to reference it with trust.

Answer (score 0):

I have R version 3.6.2 on Mac OS 10.15.6 and solved the problem as below. I assume you have Xcode tools already installed.

Step 1) Install gfortran package from  https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/

Step 2) install_version("mnormt", version = "1.5-5", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

Step 3) install.packages("psych")

In step 2, I have installed an older version of mnormt because I wanted to ensure it is compatible with my R version 3.6.2. Step 2 and 3 are done on the R console. Here is a post by some other people who have struggled with the same problem: https://community.rstudio.com/t/cant-install-psych-dependencies-mnormt/68770